# How to add and sync folders outside SkyDrive folder?

Tags: windows-8, sync, onedrive

I have folders with documents all over my hard drive, some which I would like to include in SkyDrive without moving them into the SkyDrive folder.

E.g. my SkyDrive folder is in `C:\Users\Name\SkyDrive`, but I have some files in `C:\Users\Name\SyncMePlz` that I also would like to be synced with SkyDrive so that I can reach them from other devices.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with a [Symbolic Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

What is needed is a symbolic link from inside the SkyDrive folder to the folder you want to sync. This works with both *hard* (/J) and *soft* (/D) symbolic links.

1. Open up a command prompt as Administrator:

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and select **Command Prompt (Admin)**
2. Create a symlink by writing:

   ```
   mklink /D "<path-to-skydrive>\<name-of-new-folder>;" "<path-to-folder-to-be-synced>"
   ```

   #### Example

   ```
   mklink /D "C:\Users\Name\SkyDrive\Test" "C:\Users\Name\SyncMePlz"
   ```

   - The `name-of-new-folder` (or `Test` in the example) will be the name of the folder in which the documents will be synced.

[image: how to create the link]

After doing this I now have a folder named *Test* in my SkyDrive folder that contains all the files in the *SyncMePlz* folder. And changing any file, adding a file etc. in *SyncMePlz* will automatically be updated and synced in the *Test* folder in SkyDrive across your devices.

Comment: There is a open source project with a graphical user interface for mklink. You can download it here -> http://code.google.com/p/symlinker/ You should run it as administrator.

Comment: Just in case someone else trips on this issue. Skydrive has a sync issue with symbolic links. **Skydrive sync does not get triggered when contents of Symbolic Links Change**. This means that only on start-up or restart of the app and during other changes your simlink folder would be synced. See this answer on the [MS forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-sync/skydrive-on-mac-why-ignore-symlinks/37ad9bfd-5587-416d-9d33-0dc19347e41c). As of March 27, 2013, this problem still exists.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I was looking all over how to do this and this was the only place I found that didn't involve installing some bs third party software. I didn't encounter the issues MandoMando mentioned in Windows 8.1.

Comment: Follow up, I actually had the folders reversed hence why I didn't have an issue. There does appear to still be a sym link issue in 8.1. I created my folder in C:\Users\<username>\SkyDrive then created a symlink to that where I needed it.

Comment: This is not working in Windows 8. Onedrive cannot sync such folder link at all.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is download this "shell extension," which adds a sync option to Windows' right-click menu.

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=d9969a7a68650af6&id=D9969A7A68650AF6!1126&authkey=!AMSxUTXTXoorDxQ

Comment: Welcome! Do you have any more info about this .exe? For instance a source that can be trusted. I'm generally skeptical to download and run untrusted .exe files.

Comment: This "shell extension" solution has one problem: when you added your folder to SkyDrive you actually moved your folder and leave a link in original place. It does not work for some "unmovable" folders.